# sqlalchemy pandas to_sql OperationalError

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to use pandas and sqlalchemy to write text files into a mysql database.

My code is:

```
remote_engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@192.168.1.240/test')

table = pd.read_table('data.csv', sep=',')
table.to_sql('data', remote_engine, if_exists='append')
```

the if_exists flag doesn't seem to be working though I keep getting

```
OperationalError 1050 Table 'data' already exists.
```

isn't if_exists meant to cater for this?

This is using the latest version non dev version of Pandas

Comment: Can you show `pd.__version__`? And the output of `remote_engine.has_table('data')`?

Comment: pd.__version__ = 0.14.0 the output of remote_engine_has_table is True

Comment: Can you show the output of `meta = sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData(remote_engine); meta.reflect(); meta.tables.get('data')`?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: I ended up just not using pandas to append to the db. But now that I have some time I can have another crack at it.